# Error on spatie laravel newsletter mailchimp and Laravel 10 cURL error 3

Tags: laravel

I'm working on the integration using Spatie Laravel Newsletter [ https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/laravel-newsletter] and Laravel Framework 10 somehow I got an error occurred with following message:

```
[2023-10-25 17:05:16] local.ERROR: cURL error 3: URL rejected: No host part in the URL (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for /email-lists/c46e5345a5 {"userId":2,"exception":"[object] (GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\RequestException(code: 0): cURL error 3: URL rejected: No host part in the URL (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for /email-lists/c46e5345a5 at /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:211)

[stacktrace]

#0 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(158): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\EasyHandle), Array)

#1 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(110): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory))

#2 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlHandler.php(47): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory))

#3 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/Proxy.php(28): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlHandler->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)

#4 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/Proxy.php(48): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)

#5 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/PrepareBodyMiddleware.php(35): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)

#6 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(31): GuzzleHttp\\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)

#7 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RedirectMiddleware.php(71): GuzzleHttp\\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)

#8 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(63): GuzzleHttp\\RedirectMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)

#9 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/HandlerStack.php(75): GuzzleHttp\\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)

#10 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(333): GuzzleHttp\\HandlerStack->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)

#11 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(169): GuzzleHttp\\Client->transfer(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)

#12 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(189): GuzzleHttp\\Client->requestAsync('GET', Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Uri), Array)

#13 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/spatie/mailcoach-sdk-php/src/MakesHttpRequests.php(44): GuzzleHttp\\Client->request('GET', 'email-lists/c46...', Array)

#14 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/spatie/mailcoach-sdk-php/src/MakesHttpRequests.php(16): Spatie\\MailcoachSdk\\Mailcoach->request('GET', 'email-lists/c46...')

#15 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/spatie/mailcoach-sdk-php/src/Actions/ManagesEmailLists.php(32): Spatie\\MailcoachSdk\\Mailcoach->get('email-lists/c46...')

#16 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/spatie/laravel-newsletter/src/Drivers/MailcoachDriver.php(86): Spatie\\MailcoachSdk\\Mailcoach->emailList('c46e5345a5')

#17 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/spatie/laravel-newsletter/src/Drivers/MailcoachDriver.php(98): Spatie\\Newsletter\\Drivers\\MailcoachDriver->getMember('user@gmail.com', '')

#18 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(353): Spatie\\Newsletter\\Drivers\\MailcoachDriver->isSubscribed('user@gmail.com')

#19 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/app/Http/Controllers/NewsletterController.php(12): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('isSubscribed', Array)

#20 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\NewsletterController->subscribe(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#21 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(43): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('subscribe', Array)

#22 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(260): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\NewsletterController), 'subscribe')

#23 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(205): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()

#24 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(799): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()

#25 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#26 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#27 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

#28 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#29 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

#30 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#31 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

#32 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#33 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Session\\Store), Object(Closure))

#34 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

#35 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#36 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

#37 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#38 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

#39 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#40 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(800): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))

#41 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(777): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#42 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(741): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))

#43 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(730): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#44 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(200): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#45 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#46 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#47 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

#48 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

#49 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#50 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

#51 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

#52 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#53 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

#54 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(99): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#55 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

#56 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#57 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

#58 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#59 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(175): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))

#60 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#61 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

#62 /Users/madeprisha/Documents/Bitdna/nitipv1/server.php(21): require_once('/Users/madepris...')

#63 {main}

"}
```

My controller as follow:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Newsletter;

class NewsletterController extends Controller
{
    public function subscribe(Request $request)
    {
        if ( ! Newsletter::isSubscribed($request->email) ) 
        {
            Newsletter::subscribePending($request->email);
            request()->session()->flash('success', 'Thanks For Subscribe');
        }
        request()->session()->flash('eror', 'Sorry! You have already subscribed');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Also here in my routes:

```
Route::post('subscribe', 'NewsletterController@subscribe')->name('subscribe');
```

My `config/newsletter.php`

```
<?php

return [

    /*
     * The API key of a MailChimp account. You can find yours at
     * https://us10.admin.mailchimp.com/account/api-key-popup/.
     */
    'apiKey' => env('MAILCHIMP_APIKEY'),

    /*
     * The listName to use when no listName has been specified in a method.
     */
    'defaultListName' => 'subscribers',

    /*
     * Here you can define properties of the lists.
     */
    'lists' => [

        /*
         * This key is used to identify this list. It can be used
         * as the listName parameter provided in the various methods.
         *
         * You can set it to any string you want and you can add
         * as many lists as you want.
         */
        'subscribers' => [

            /*
             * A MailChimp list id. Check the MailChimp docs if you don't know
             * how to get this value:
             * http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/managing-subscribers/find-your-list-id.
             */
            'id' => env('MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID'),
        ],
    ],

    /*
     * If you're having trouble with https connections, set this to false.
     */
    'ssl' => true,

];
```

I've been searching out but its pointed to cUrl Error 3 however all of the packages on the composer are work just fine and only issue with the Spatie Laravel Newsletter. Can someone help me out how to solve the error that I encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message pretty much tells that the request failed due to no host provided:

```
cURL error 3: URL rejected: No host part in the URL (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for /email-lists/c46e5345a5
```

From the package documentation, perhaps you need to install an additional package (depending on the driver you used) and configure it, especially on this section:

```php
'driver' => env('NEWSLETTER_DRIVER', Spatie\Newsletter\Drivers\MailcoachDriver::class),
'driver_arguments' => [
    'api_key' => env('NEWSLETTER_API_KEY'),
    'endpoint' => env('NEWSLETTER_ENDPOINT'),
],
```

Comment: But I wasn't using Mailcoach, as I can see it, is it supposed to be
```
/*
     * The driver to use to interact with MailChimp API.
     * You may use "log" or "null" to prevent calling the
     * API directly from your environment.
     */
```
Is it `log` or `null` I don't know which one?

Comment: @Aeterno from the stack trace above shows that you're currently using Mailcoach driver. Maybe you didn't set the `driver` configuration correctly?

Comment: I've tried encountered same issue 
```
cURL error 3: (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for /email-lists/c46e5345a5
```

Comment: @Aeterno if you're using Mailchimp, make sure to set the `driver` config to `Spatie\Newsletter\Drivers\MailChimpDriver::class` and set the `endpoint` to null. Be sure to install `drewm/mailchimp-api` package as well.

Comment: Thank you it solved but I found the email are not being updated on the mailchimp contact